# How will the Chakra Jscript engine be exposed to Scripting Hosts?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, chakra

Anybody has experience with the upcoming IE9 Chakra engine?  I am currently considering whether to incorporate the Microsoft's JScript engine through the Window Script Interface or using one of those open source javascript engines (tracemonkey/v8 etc).

The JScript engine is a bit too slow and Chakra looks promising.  But I am not sure if it will be accessible the same way as before since Active Scripting should be deprecated.

Anybody get some idea?

Comment: I would love to know this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware that ActiveScripting is deprecated - I've seen no statement from Microsoft along those lines.

Microsoft's documentation suggests that [IE9's Javascript engine (code-named "chakra") still gets loaded by IActiveScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95%28v=VS.94%29.aspx).  Though MS does not document a ProgId or CLSID, [there is a CLSID you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690/what-is-the-progid-or-clsid-for-ie9s-javascript-engine-code-named-chakra/7168837#7168837):

> {16d51579-a30b-4c8b-a276-0ff4dc41e755}

The C# code to load the Chakra scripting engine looks like this:

```
    var guid = new System.Guid("{16d51579-a30b-4c8b-a276-0ff4dc41e755}");
    Type engineType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid, true);
    var engine = Activator.CreateInstance(engineType) as IActiveScript;
```

In my limited tests in various micro-benchmarks, Chakra is about 2x the speed of JScript v5.8.

See also:
[What is the ProgId or CLSID for IE9's Javascript engine (code-named "Chakra")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690/)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in checking this out too: [JavaScript Runtime Hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249673%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

It's not ActiveScript but it gives you very low level access to Chakra in a very nice new API.