# Embedding Chakra Javascript Engine in Windows 8 / .Net 4.5

Tags: javascript, .net, windows-8, chakra

Given the rise of Javascript in Windows 8, does Windows 8 / .Net 4.5 / VS 2012 provide a mechanism to embed the Chakra javascript engine in application to enable scripting?  If so, is there documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might be able to use another JavaScript implementation like Jint or IronJS. (Jurassic probably wouldn't work -- it P/Invokes to V8 and I don't think P/Invoke is allowed in Metro apps.)

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690/what-is-the-progid-or-clsid-for-ie9s-javascript-engine-code-named-chakra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism to do this that has been released or talked about.  For now, it is available only in IE and to Metro style apps.  There isn't even a Windows Scripting Host style exposure of it.

What is it about Chakra that you want in your scripting?

Comment: Hi Steve, in my case, I would need to invoke javascript from both a Windows Store App and from WPF.  We are developing an App for Windows 8 and its little brother from pre-Windows 8 in WPF.  I would need to use JavaScript as a scripting language.  So I would have, on one hand, a string representing a script and an object model in .NET.  I would need to pass that object model to the script in order for the script to run on it.  Any way you see to that in both Win Store App & traditional .NET?  It could be two different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't IE ActiveX use the same JavaScript engine as IE standalone?

You can simply embed Internet Explorer ActiveX frame and keep it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exists.

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/wiki/Embedding-ChakraCore

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using ChakraHost.Hosting;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main() {
    JavaScriptRuntime runtime;
    JavaScriptContext context;
    JavaScriptSourceContext currentSourceContext = JavaScriptSourceContext.FromIntPtr(IntPtr.Zero);
    JavaScriptValue result;

    // Your script, try replace the basic hello world with something else
    string script = "(()=>{return \'Hello world!\';})()";

    // Create a runtime. 
    Native.JsCreateRuntime(JavaScriptRuntimeAttributes.None, null, out runtime);

    // Create an execution context. 
    Native.JsCreateContext(runtime, out context);

    // Now set the execution context as being the current one on this thread.
    Native.JsSetCurrentContext(context);

    // Run the script.
    Native.JsRunScript(script, currentSourceContext++, "", out result);

    // Convert your script result to String in JavaScript; redundant if your script returns a String
    JavaScriptValue resultJSString;
    Native.JsConvertValueToString(result, out resultJSString);

    // Project script result in JS back to C#.
    IntPtr resultPtr;
    UIntPtr stringLength;
    Native.JsStringToPointer(resultJSString, out resultPtr, out stringLength);

    string resultString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(resultPtr);
    Console.WriteLine(resultString);
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Dispose runtime
    Native.JsSetCurrentContext(JavaScriptContext.Invalid);
    Native.JsDisposeRuntime(runtime);
}
```

}

Comment: Please consider adding a code example on stackoverflow as the link might break or the repo might be removed.